# CSS Расстояние между header и footer пустой галереи

Tags: css, header, gallery

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы хедер и футер были пришиты к верхнему и нижнему краям экрана cоответственно при пустой галереи (до запроса на бекенд)?

Comment: Вот тут можно без особых усилий такое смастерить онлайн... http://createtemplate.hellohtml.ru

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас есть какой-либо контейнер, то его можно растянуть через flex-grow: 1; 
Если же нет, то футеру добавить margin-top: auto;

```css
*{padding: 0; margin: 0;}
html {
height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display:none;
  background:red;
}
footer {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <header>header</header>
  <main>main</main>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</body>
</html>
```